# Google API: Can't include "Google_Client.php"

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api

Here are my files in the sublime explorer:

[image]

I can include config.php but not the other:

```
echo get_include_path();                                            //output: .:/usr/local/pear/share/pear
set_include_path(SITE_SERVER.'vendor/google-api-php-client/src');
echo get_include_path();                                            //output: /Users/harrywiles/Dropbox/Sites/headfirst/vendor/google-api-php-client/src
require_once 'config.php';                                          //works
require_once 'Google_Client.php';                                   //doesnt work
```

I get the classic error even though i know the paths are correct:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Google_Client.php' (include_path='/Users/harrywiles/Dropbox/Sites/headfirst/vendor/google-api-php-client/src')
```

This is driving me mental so any help really appreciated!

Comment: Could be something about the file permissons. Is chmod of both files the same?

Comment: Just as a sanity check can you verify against one of the sample apps? The PHP samples are here: code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples and we have a video about how to load the samples here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMhN6pCAZWo&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2

Comment: @Ikaj - yep, i was trying the samples. I just cut everything else out and narrowed it down to this "require"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a permission error. Just go to the root of your project and run

> chmod -R 755 *

If apache doesn't have permission to read and execute, that will raise these problems.